# Drawing a 2 x 2 Square and an L

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following two images. I heard using tikz may be of some help.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\psset{dimen=medusa}

\def\L{\multips(0,1){3}{\psframe(1,1)}\psframe(1,2)(2,3)}
\def\C{\multips(1,0){2}{\multips(0,1){2}{\psframe(1,1)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,4)
    \L\rput(3,0){\C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `dimen=monkey` or just simply `dimen=m` to save more keystrokes.

Comment: I get the error message: undefined control sequence \psset

Comment: @David: Compile it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`.